# Disabling all Fields on a Form in CRM 2015

Tags: javascript, c#, crm

hi I want Disable all fields on a frorm in CRM 2015 on save using plugin or Jscript

Comment: The question that is listed as a duplicate is not.  In CRM Disabling all fields on a form is different than all fields of a section on the form

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.forEach(function (attribute, index) {    
    var control = Xrm.Page.getControl(attribute.getName());
    if (control) {
        control.setDisabled(true)
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you !! it's working (sorry about my english :p )

Comment: This won't disable header attributes, or Business Process Flow Attributes

Comment: Thanks! Busy upgrading from 2011 to 2016 and this worked first time around, Header and Footer included.