# Record security based on option set value

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

For the accounts entity I have different account types.
However I need to make some of these records read only only based on the account type, as these records will be slaved in CRM.

However the user should still have ability to create other types of accounts that will be mastered in CRM.

I was thinking to do this via security role however when giving create or edit permission on the account entity user can still create accounts of any type or edit existing slaved data.

What would be the best way to make slaved data read only?
Use business rules to lock all fields based on the type?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, this cannot be achieved with security role, since the requirement is based on a field value.

[Disabling all the form fields in bulk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28169295/7920473) - You can do this in javascript quickly, or may be with Business rules one by one. Verify the field value on form load for your certain slaved value account type, then disable the controls by iterating each one of them.

Still subgrid, webresource, iframes will be editable.

Comment: Also everything done in JavaScript can be undone in JavaScript :)