# Set form read only using Xrm Object on Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, xrm

I am reading about **Xrm object** on [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602964.aspx) but I can't find something concrete.

I need to restrict some roles of creating or editing a *portal comment* (type of *activity*). Therefore I can't just simply modify *security roles*.

I see when I edit the portal comment form that there is a JavaScript script which executes on Page load:

[image: Page load script]

When editing this it uses a lot this `Xrm` object.

In pseudocode I should do

```
if(ActiveUser.hasRoles(["Some role", "Some other role"]) {
    Page.setReadOnly(true);
}
```

I already have a script (as a web resource) to check the roles like this but I don't know how to make the form "read only" or make this with Xrm only. Any clues how to achieve this here?

**Edit 1:**

I was able to do this by using the following code:

```
// Ribbon "Save" button
document.querySelector('#crmRibbonManager').style.display = "none";
// Status "Save" button
document.querySelector('#savefooter_statuscontrol').style.display = "none";
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get().forEach(function (control) {          
    if(!control.getDisabled()) {
        control.setDisabled(true);
    }
});
```

Of course I get ***Page Load error*** since the **document** is not loaded yet. But I am pretty sure I could use some `Xrm` technique to disable these attributes, I have to study that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on right track. Like you said, create/modify your js library web resource & register on form load rather than editing the existing OOB adx form scripting js file. In your js code - check the current user's [security roles](https://muralikrishnasabbavarapublog.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/lock-unlock-the-field-based-on-user-security-role-in-crm/).

```
Xrm.Page.context.getUserRoles();
```

Then disable the [fields in bulk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28169295/7920473).

```
Xrm.Page.getControl("myfield").setDisabled(true);
```

Dynamics 365 CRM platform has [two forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui/getformtype) namely Read-only & Disabled, former is loaded when user has only Read privilege for that particular entity & latter rendered for Inactive records. Unfortunately we cannot force to load of any of these forms.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Arun's answer;

This type of stuff is unsupported; `document.querySelector('#crmRibbonManager')`

[Microsoft Dynamics 365 and the importance of staying supported](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2017/06/25/microsoft-dynamics-365-and-the-importance-of-staying-supported/)

> All JavaScript interactions within the application pages must only be
>   performed using functions defined in Xrm.Page & Xrm.Utility
>   namespaces, i.e. don’t directly interact with the page DOM.

If you want to control ribbon behaviours you should [Customize commands and the ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309639.aspx), you will need to add an enable/display rule. [Ribbon Workbench](http://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx) is a great tool for this.

Finally, it's worth nothing that this only controls client side validation. If you want server side rules the user can't avoid, you should look into implementing a plugin.